# Persistent: List field not working with PostgreSQL's JSONB

Tags: postgresql, haskell, persistent, jsonb

I'm using `persistent`/`persistent-postgresql` together with Liquibase for database migrations (= with an already existing database). I have following table:

```
mkPersist sqlSettings { mpsGeneric=False } [persistLowerCase|
Entry sql=entries
    keywords [T.Text] sqltype=jsonb
|]
```

I thought persistent would automatically handle the list by (de)serialising it from/to JSON. Unfortunately a select throws following exception:

```
Exception: PersistMarshalError "field keywords: Expected PersistList, received: PersistByteString \"[\\\"english\\\"]\""
```

Why doesn't it parse the column as a JSON list?

Comment: Possibly a related issue: https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/585

Comment: @Sibi: I'm not sure about that. I can change the `sqltype` to `json` (or omit it) and it makes no difference. According to a comment in following link, lists should be converted to JSON: https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/358#issuecomment-73907728 . I'm probably missing something...

Comment: Can you share your `persistent` model file which has the schema definition ?

Comment: @Sibi: What exactly do you want to see? I edited the question and added the `mkPersist` declaration. This is the entire schema I have in my test. I then just try to get all rows with `select $ from return` (using `Esqueleto`).